# Comparing detected communities with ground truth

Tags: r, igraph, modularity

I have an igraph where the vertexes have an attribute that describes the known community:

```
g=sample_gnm(10, 30, directed = F, loops = F)
communities=c("a", "b", "c")
E(g)$known_community=sample(communities, length(E(g)), replace = T)
```

Then I detect the community with fastgreedy:

```
g_com=fastgreedy.community(g)
```

I need to compare the communities detected by the algorithm to the known communities. Is there any way to get an igraph communities object from the vertexes info so I can use compare()? If not how could I compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `?help` page for `compare`. It says:

> A communities object containing a community structure; or a numeric
>   vector, the membership vector of the first community structure. The
>   membership vector should contain the community id of each vertex, the
>   numbering of the communities starts with one.

So `compare` can compare either `communities` objects or numeric vectors with same length as the number of vertices. You simulated a network with 10 vertices, so your list of communities should also have length 10. Your mistake is that you try to define a vector of communities based on your *edges* rather than your vertices, so you vector has length 30.

The following approach works.

```
# Load igraph
library(igraph)

# Random graph
v <- 10
e <- 30
g <- sample_gnm(v, e, directed = F, loops = F)

# Known communities
com <- sample(1:3, v, replace=TRUE) 

# Optimum communities
opt <- fastgreedy.community(g)

# Compare
compare(com, opt)
```

Comment: Ah didn't realized I was using the edges on the example nor that I could use compare with a vector. Thank you!